# iPad compatibility

Tags: ipad, scrollbar

I have a web-application developed with jQuery with a web2.0 look & feel.

All the popups (window.open) have been substituted with a modal div widget similar to the the jQuery ui modal form.

I have the problem that when the content is very long the vertical scroll-bar is not displayed and the content exits the div where is contained.

A first solution was to open the content in a new window (with window.open) only for iPad.
This works for static content: the problem is that when the content has to interact with the page where it was loaded I receive a lot of javascript errors since with window.open the "parent" page is not visible anymore.

Is there a pattern for this kind of problems?
Kind regards
Massimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution referring in that cases on window opener instead of the parent.